# Mass update product description programmatically Magento

Tags: magento

I need to update description on more than 1000 products. I use this code to do this task. It works but the created_at and updated_at fields got messed up after running this code. Did I miss something?

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 10.00))
            ;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $desc = $product->getDescription();
    $descUp = $desc.'<p>New Text Here</p>';
    $update = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    $update->setStoreId(0);
    $update->setDescription($descUp);
    try {
        $update->save();
        echo "<pre>".$product->getSku(). " updated</pre>";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it:

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
        ->getResource();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 10.00));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $attrData = array(); // Array of attributes to mass update for the product
    $attrData['description'] = $product->getDescription() . '<p>New Text Here</p>';
    //$attrData['other_attr'] = 'value';

    // Mass update action, 0 - Store ID
    $model->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), $attrData, 0);
}
```

Comment: I've already modified the product description directly through database manipulation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please explain why is this a better way? The mass update action is still inside the loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ErvinLlojku It's better because there is no product load and product save which are slow. In my example I only use product collection and then use product_action model to update attributes. It's way faster then Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)->setDescription('blabla')->save();

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Magmi, http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ ? You can manage all the details in a spreadsheet and load and reload and overwrite data as many times as you want.